# How to get all html data after all scripts and page loading is done? (puppeteer)

Tags: javascript, node.js, parsing, web-scraping, puppeteer

Finally I figured how to use Node.js. Installed all libraries/extensions. So puppeteer is working, but as it was previous with Xmlhttp... it gets only template/body of the page, without needed information. All scripts on the page engage after few second it had been opened in browser (Web app?). I need to get information inside certain tags after Whole page is loaded. Also, I would ask, if it possible to have pure JavaScript, because I do not use jQuery like code. So it doubles difficulty for me...

Here what I have so far.

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
const $ = require('cheerio');
let browser;
let page;

const url = "really long link with latitude and attitude";

(async () => puppeteer
  .launch()
  .then(await function(browser) {
    return browser.newPage();
})
  .then(await function(page) {
    return page.goto(url).then(function() {
      return page.content();
    });
  })
  .then(await function(html) {
    $('strong', html).each(function() {
      console.log($(this).text());
    });
  })
  .catch(function(err) {
    //handle error
  }))();
```

I get only template default body elements inside strong tag. But it should contain a lot more data than just 10 items.

Comment: It's a bit odd to use `async/await` *and* `then()`. Usually it would be `const browser = await puppeteer.launch(); const page = await browser.newPage();`... etc.

Answer (score 41):

If you want full html same as inspect? Here it is:

```
    const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

    (async function main() {
      try {
        const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
        const [page] = await browser.pages();

        await page.goto('https://example.org/', { waitUntil: 'networkidle0' });
        const data = await page.evaluate(() => document.querySelector('*').outerHTML);

        console.log(data);

        await browser.close();
      } catch (err) {
        console.error(err);
      }
    })();
```

Comment: how is this different than `await page.content()`?

Comment: @chovy no different from `document.documentElement.outerHTML` https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/30c6b13eec4cebf4fe4e5ec069169b562750558e/packages/puppeteer-core/src/common/IsolatedWorld.ts#L282

Answer (score 20):

**Just [one line](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/issues/331#issuecomment-455957224)**:

```js
const html = await page.content();
```

**Details**:

```js
import puppeteer from 'puppeteer'

const test = async (url) => {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ headless: false })
    const page = await browser.newPage()

    await page.goto(url, { waitUntil: 'networkidle0' })

    const html = await page.content()
    console.log(html)
}

await test('https://stackoverflow.com/')
```

Answer (score 11):

`let bodyHTML = await page.evaluate(() =>  document.documentElement.outerHTML);`

This

Comment: however this may answer the question, please find some words to describe your solution.

Answer (score 8):

Some notes:

1. You need not `cheerio` with `puppeteer` and you need not reparse `page.content()`: you already have the full DOM with all scripts run and you can evaluate any code in `window` context like in a browser using [`page.evaluate()`](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#pageevaluatepagefunction-args) and transferring serializable data between web API context and Node.js API context.
2. Try to use async/await only, this will simplify your code and flow.
3. If you need to wait till all the scripts and other dependencies are loaded, use `waitUntil: 'networkidle0'` in [`page.goto()`](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#pagegotourl-options).
4. If you suspect that document scripts need some time till the needed state, use various test functions like [`page.waitForSelector()`](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#pagewaitforselectorselector-options) or fall back to [`page.waitFor(milliseconds)`](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#pagewaitforselectororfunctionortimeout-options-args).

Here is a simple script that outputs all tag names in a page.

```js
'use strict';

const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

(async function main() {
  try {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
    const [page] = await browser.pages();

    await page.goto('https://example.org/', { waitUntil: 'networkidle0' });

    const data = await page.evaluate(
      () =>  Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('*'))
                  .map(elem => elem.tagName)
    );

    console.log(data);

    await browser.close();
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
  }
})();
```

You can specify your task in more details and we can try to write something more appropriate.

---

Script for www.bezrealitky.cz (task from a comment below):

```js
'use strict';

const fs = require('fs');
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

(async function main() {
  try {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
    const [page] = await browser.pages();
    page.setDefaultTimeout(0);

    await page.goto('https://www.bezrealitky.cz/vyhledat?offerType=pronajem&estateType=byt&disposition=&ownership=&construction=&equipped=&balcony=&order=timeOrder_desc&boundary=%5B%5B%7B%22lat%22%3A50.171436864513%2C%22lng%22%3A14.506905276796942%7D%2C%7B%22lat%22%3A50.154133576294%2C%22lng%22%3A14.599004629591036%7D%2C%7B%22lat%22%3A50.14524430128%2C%22lng%22%3A14.58773054712799%7D%2C%7B%22lat%22%3A50.129307131988%2C%22lng%22%3A14.60087568578706%7D%2C%7B%22lat%22%3A50.122604734575%2C%22lng%22%3A14.659116306376973%7D%2C%7B%22lat%22%3A50.106512499343%2C%22lng%22%3A14.657434650206028%7D%2C%7B%22lat%22%3A50.090685542974%2C%22lng%22%3A14.705099547441932%7D%2C%7B%22lat%22%3A50.072175921973%2C%22lng%22%3A14.700004206235008%7D%2C%7B%22lat%22%3A50.056898491904%2C%22lng%22%3A14.640206899053055%7D%2C%7B%22lat%22%3A50.038528576841%2C%22lng%22%3A14.666852728301023%7D%2C%7B%22lat%22%3A50.030955909657%2C%22lng%22%3A14.656128752460972%7D%2C%7B%22lat%22%3A50.013435368522%2C%22lng%22%3A14.66854956530301%7D%2C%7B%22lat%22%3A49.99444182116%2C%22lng%22%3A14.640153080292066%7D%2C%7B%22lat%22%3A50.010839032542%2C%22lng%22%3A14.527474219359988%7D%2C%7B%22lat%22%3A49.970771602447%2C%22lng%22%3A14.46224174052395%7D%2C%7B%22lat%22%3A49.970669964027%2C%22lng%22%3A14.400648545303966%7D%2C%7B%22lat%22%3A49.941901176098%2C%22lng%22%3A14.395563234671044%7D%2C%7B%22lat%22%3A49.948384148423%2C%22lng%22%3A14.337635637038034%7D%2C%7B%22lat%22%3A49.958376114735%2C%22lng%22%3A14.324977842107955%7D%2C%7B%22lat%22%3A49.9676286223%2C%22lng%22%3A14.34491711110104%7D%2C%7B%22lat%22%3A49.971859099005%2C%22lng%22%3A14.326815050839059%7D%2C%7B%22lat%22%3A49.990608728081%2C%22lng%22%3A14.342731259186962%7D%2C%7B%22lat%22%3A50.002211140429%2C%22lng%22%3A14.29483886971002%7D%2C%7B%22lat%22%3A50.023596577558%2C%22lng%22%3A14.315872285282012%7D%2C%7B%22lat%22%3A50.058309376419%2C%22lng%22%3A14.248086830069042%7D%2C%7B%22lat%22%3A50.073179111%2C%22lng%22%3A14.290193274400963%7D%2C%7B%22lat%22%3A50.102973823639%2C%22lng%22%3A14.224439442359994%7D%2C%7B%22lat%22%3A50.130060800171%2C%22lng%22%3A14.302396419107936%7D%2C%7B%22lat%22%3A50.116019827009%2C%22lng%22%3A14.360785349547996%7D%2C%7B%22lat%22%3A50.148005694843%2C%22lng%22%3A14.365662825877052%7D%2C%7B%22lat%22%3A50.14142969454%2C%22lng%22%3A14.394903042943952%7D%2C%7B%22lat%22%3A50.171436864513%2C%22lng%22%3A14.506905276796942%7D%2C%7B%22lat%22%3A50.171436864513%2C%22lng%22%3A14.506905276796942%7D%5D%5D&hasDrawnBoundary=1&mapBounds=%5B%5B%7B%22lat%22%3A50.289447077141126%2C%22lng%22%3A14.68724263943227%7D%2C%7B%22lat%22%3A50.289447077141126%2C%22lng%22%3A14.087801111111958%7D%2C%7B%22lat%22%3A50.039169221047985%2C%22lng%22%3A14.087801111111958%7D%2C%7B%22lat%22%3A50.039169221047985%2C%22lng%22%3A14.68724263943227%7D%2C%7B%22lat%22%3A50.289447077141126%2C%22lng%22%3A14.68724263943227%7D%5D%5D&center=%7B%22lat%22%3A50.16447196305031%2C%22lng%22%3A14.387521875272125%7D&zoom=11&locationInput=praha&limit=15');

    await page.waitForSelector('#search-content button.btn-icon');

    while (await page.$('#search-content button.btn-icon') !== null) {
      const articlesForNow = (await page.$$('#search-content article')).length;
      console.log(`Articles for now: ${articlesForNow}. Getting more...`);

      await Promise.all([
        page.evaluate(
          () => { document.querySelector('#search-content button.btn-icon').click(); }
        ),
        page.waitForFunction(
          old => document.querySelectorAll('#search-content article').length > old,
          {},
          articlesForNow
        ),
      ]);
    }

    const articlesAll = (await page.$$('#search-content article')).length;
    console.log(`All articles: ${articlesAll}.`);

    fs.writeFileSync('full.html', await page.content());
    fs.writeFileSync('articles.html', await page.evaluate(
      () => document.querySelector('#search-content div.b-filter__inner').outerHTML
    ));
    fs.writeFileSync('articles.txt', await page.evaluate(
      () => [...document.querySelectorAll('#search-content article')]
              .map(({ innerText }) => innerText)
              .join(`\n${'-'.repeat(50)}\n`)
    ));
    console.log('Saved.');

    await browser.close();
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
  }
})();
```

Comment: thanks, that works, but i have another question. On the page, there is button, and i need to press it to get more items, how do i do that? And also, if possible, i want to get html with All data, and parse it through queryselector myself, it would be much easier for me.

Comment: This depends on the button click effect: does it start navigation, send fetch or XHR request or just make some dynamic DOM manipulation. As for the second question, I am not sure I understand the issue. Maybe you can provide the URL and describe what you need to achive?

Comment: tinyurl.com/y9vgf2h7
There is button below all apartments offer, to load more. I want to get HTML of this page with All appartments offer, to parse it later with querySelector.

Comment: Do you mean "Zobrazit dalších 15 nabídek" button? Do you want to click on it till all the offers are shown? I've clicked on it several times and the list still grows. Is this list growth finite?

Comment: Yes, this button. I think it has end :). At least i remember it had.

Comment: Well, not the most efficient UI (more than 1000 offers on one page and growing — this works rather slow at the end), But I've managed to retrieve all the1283 offers for the URL. The script is added to the answer: it saves all the page in `full.html` and only the part with offers in `articles.html` just to illustrate various ways to dump the data.

Comment: Also added an output to `articles.txt` in just a simple readable format: `innerText` of each article separated by a line.

Comment: Do you mean writing something similar or using the script to get the data? If you mean rewriting, puppeteer docs are good and not so big. If you mean using, what issue do you have?

Comment: i mean understand this pupeter library, and also jquery code, because i write only pure JS, so editing your code its just combine with pure JS :) but your code is doing the job i wanted, thank you.

Comment: I do not know jquery  as well) My code is also pure JS with some puppeteer API (including methods that start with `$`)

Comment: Where does `document` come from in a node context?

Comment: @1252748 There is no `document` in a node context. Functions with `document` are recreated and launched in the browser context.

Answer (score -1):

The answers above are essentially correct, i.e. the main ingredient is:

```
await page.goto('https://example.org/', { waitUntil: 'networkidle0' });
```

However, in practice, some sites will try to make themselves scrape-unfriendly by also checking the `User-Agent` header. So if you want the DOM to look like it would in a real browser, you might also need:

```
await page.setExtraHTTPHeaders({
    "User-Agent":
      "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/113.0.0.0 Safari/537.36",
  });
await page.goto(url, { waitUntil: "networkidle0" });
```