# Node-fetch not providing all HTML from a page in body

Tags: node.js, cheerio, node-fetch

I'm using cheerio and node-fetch to get all the product links on a specific URL.

I get back an array of links, but the list is incomplete as the body is missing the HTML with the product links.

```
fetch('https://shop.gossmanknives.com/shop?olsPage=products')
    .then(res => res.text())
    .then(body => {
        $ = cheerio.load(body);
        let snapshot = $("a, [data-ux='Link']")
            .map((i, x) => $(x).attr('href'))
            .toArray();
        console.log(snapshot);
    });
```

This is the array returned:

```
['#', '/', '/', '/', '/shop','#', '/', '/shop', '/', '/shop', 'https://www.godaddy.com/websites/website-builder?isc=pwugc&utm_source=wsb&utm_medium=applications&utm_campaign=en-us_corp_applications_base']
```

This seems odd as there is an element like the below that *should* be picked up, but it appears the 'body' returned by fetch() is missing a bunch of the HTML I see with view source. Not sure why. Perhaps the data is dynamic and isn't on the page when fetch() runs?

```
<a rel="" typography="LinkAlpha" data-ux="Link" data-aid="PRODUCT_NAME_RENDERED_Orion" data-page="https://shop.gossmanknives.com/shop" data-page-query="olsPage=products/orion-aebl-black" href="https://shop.gossmanknives.com/shop?olsPage=products/orion-aebl-black" class="x-el x-el-a c2-9 c2-a c2-b c2-c c2-d c2-61 c2-f c2-3 c2-43 c2-4 c2-o c2-62 c2-63 c2-5 c2-6 c2-7 c2-8 x-d-ux x-d-aid x-d-page x-d-page-query" data-tccl="ux2.SHOP.shop1.Section.Default.Link.Default.43.click,click"><div data-ux="ProductCard" class="x-el x-el-div x-el c2-1 c2-2 c2-3 c2-4 c2-5 c2-6 c2-7 c2-8 x-d-ux c2-1 c2-2 c2-3 c2-4 c2-5 c2-6 c2-7 c2-8 x-d-ux"><div data-ux="ProductAsset" name="Orion" class="x-el x-el-div c2-1 c2-2 c2-1e c2-64 c2-65 c2-33 c2-4d c2-66 c2-2y c2-2z c2-30 c2-31 c2-3 c2-4 c2-5 c2-6 c2-7 c2-8 x-d-ux"><div id="guacBg20" role="img" data-ux="Background" data-aid="PRODUCT_IMAGE_RENDERED_Orion" treatmentdata="[object Object]" class="x-el x-el-div c2-1 c2-2 c2-67 c2-68 c2-69 c2-6a c2-1g c2-6b c2-6c c2-1t c2-1i c2-6d c2-71 c2-3 c2-4 c2-5 c2-6 c2-7 c2-8 x-d-ux x-d-aid" data-guac-image="loaded"><script>new guacImage('https://img1.wsimg.com/isteam/ip/94c95d7f-6505-4bfd-9837-ff1bcff87400/ols/IMG_0005-0002.JPG/:/rs=w:{width},h:{height},cg:false,m',document.getElementById('guacBg20'),{"useTreatmentData":true,"backgroundLayers":["linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(22, 22, 22, 0) 0%, rgba(22, 22, 22, 0) 100%)"]})</script></div></div><div data-ux="ProductName" class="x-el x-el-div c2-1 c2-2 c2-6f c2-e c2-4j c2-g c2-3z c2-3 c2-4 c2-6g c2-5 c2-6 c2-7 c2-8 x-d-ux"><p typography="BodyAlpha" data-ux="Text" class="x-el x-el-p c2-1 c2-2 c2-c c2-d c2-4u c2-x c2-y c2-3y c2-6h c2-3 c2-6i c2-12 x-d-ux">Orion</p></div><div data-ux="ProductPrices" class="x-el x-el-div c2-1 c2-2 c2-6j c2-3y c2-3 c2-4 c2-5 c2-6 c2-7 c2-8 x-d-ux"><div typography="BodyAlpha" data-ux="Price" price="[object Object]" data-aid="PRODUCT_PRICE_RENDERED_Orion" class="x-el x-el-div c2-1 c2-2 c2-c c2-d c2-4u c2-x c2-y c2-t c2-3y c2-6k c2-3 c2-6i c2-12 x-d-ux x-d-aid">$365.00</div></div><p typography="DetailsAlpha" data-ux="ProductLabel" data-aid="PRODUCT_SHIP_FREE_RENDERED_Orion" class="x-el x-el-p c2-1 c2-1p c2-c c2-d c2-4u c2-6f c2-y c2-3y c2-28 c2-4r c2-3 c2-12 c2-29 c2-6q c2-2a c2-2b c2-2c x-d-ux x-d-aid">Free Shipping</p></div></a>
```

Note I'm using https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-fetch

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your selector is wrong, you're searching for either `<a>` or any element with attribute `[data-ux='Link']`. So you pick up a lot of links that don't have the attribute. To get only links with the attribute simply pass `"a [data-ux='Link']"`

Then the navigation to the product page is through URL query. It seems that cheerio strips the URL from the query part for some reason.

Notice that in the array there's a lot of `"/shop"` values, these are probably `"/shop?something=123..."`. Try to log the whole `<a>` element and see what you can do from there.

Comment: Thanks for the reply - Turns out the body is missing the info pre-cheerio. The call was returning before dynamic data was loaded.  Addressed with puppeteer.

Answer (score 0):

Data to body was not there as it was dynamic HTML.

Used puppeteer ([original source here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60617981/2004742)) and things are a-ok.

```
    getContents(url, name) {
    (async function main() {
        try {
            const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
            const [page] = await browser.pages();

            await page.goto(url, { waitUntil: 'networkidle0' });
            const data = await page.evaluate(() => document.querySelector('*').outerHTML);

            console.log(data);

            await browser.close();
        } catch (err) {
            console.error(err);
        }
    })();
},
```